# How to add a footer to a view?

Tags: iphone, footer

I am new to iphone development.I am creating a map application.I want to display a footer in a view below the mapview in the  view.On clicking a button map leads me to the map view where i have to display the footer.Please guide me.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically accomplish this by adding a label at the bottom of the view.

Comment: I want to add a button to the footer and the button performs some other action.So should i add a button to the label